# Nancy returns CORS error on 500 error

Tags: .net, nancy, http-status-code-500

I've got a .NET app running using Nancy.  I can successfully GET data from the API endpoints via a react app, however if there's a server side error, then I get a CORS error.

I don't receive a CORS error in Postman, although I never did anyway before I put the CORS code in.

**Cors Extension**

```
    public static void UseCors(this IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(ctx => ctx.Response
            .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS")
            .WithHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Origin, Content-Type"));
    }
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        pipelines.UseCors();
        pipelines.UseErrorResponses();

        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
    }
```

The error I get back in the Google Chrome console is:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:62187/shops/v1/orders. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried adding the CORS headers to the `OnError` pipeline but it didn't seem to change anything.